# Setting HTML bgcolor With Cookies Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cookies, submit

I'm brand new to using cookies in webpages, as well as AJAX and JavaScript in general. What I'm looking to do is have a button on an HTML doc, that when pressed/submitted, sets a background color cookie = to a specified value.

Now, I can sort of see the structure of how this would work, but it would really help me if someone could give me a more in depth explanation on how I could accomplish it.

I know that I need to set something up like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            // AJAX code
            // some function that is called to set the color
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        // a submit button that 'onclick' calls the AJAX function
    </body>
</html>
```

But I'm finding the specifics hard to figure out, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You should look into using [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Comment: Can you try the plunk in my response below? it will set the cookie based on user's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ajax success, you will call the setCookie method:

```
function setCookie() {
  $.cookie("myCookie", $("#cookie_val").val(), {
    expires: 365,
    path: '/'
  });
}
```

Check out this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SYE3sLAklF1MDIidCahF?p=preview